# ggplot bubble graph custom colors

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this dataframe that I'm trying to use custom colors

```
data <- data.frame(condition=c('1','1','1','1','1','2','2','2','2','2','3','3','3','3','3'), AssessmentGrade=c('400','410','420','430','440','500','510','520','530','540','300','310','320','330','340'), Freq=c('1','2','1','5','7','9','1','5','3','4','5','8','1','3','5'), MathGrade=c('A+','B-','C-','D','F','A-','B','C+','D-','F','A+','D','D','F','C'), Condition=c('Condition 1','Condition 1','Condition 1','Condition 1','Condition 1','Condition 2','Condition 2','Condition 2','Condition 2','Condition 2','Condition 3','Condition 3','Condition 3','Condition 3','Condition 3'))
```

I used ggplot to get abubble graph but I was wondering how I would edit it to use my company's standard colors

```
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = MathGrade, y = AssessmentGrade, size = Freq, fill = Condition)) +
 geom_point(aes(colour = Condition)) +
 ggtitle("Main Title") +
 labs(x = "First Math Grade", y = "Math Assessment Score")
```

I have a vector called colors:

```
colors
[1] "#101820" "#AF272F" "#EAAA00"
```

and I tried to graph it with this:

p <- p + scale_fill_manual(values = color)

nothing changed. I tried following directions [here](http://t-redactyl.io/blog/2016/02/creating-plots-in-r-using-ggplot2-part-6-weighted-scatterplots.html) but nothing changed. Can someone assist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You create a palette:

```
my_colors<- c("#101820", "#AF272F", "#EAAA00")
```

Then when it comes time you use that in your plot:

```
 p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = MathGrade, y = AssessmentGrade, size = Freq, fill = Condition)) +
 geom_point(shape=21) +
 ggtitle("Main Title") +
 labs(x = "First Math Grade", y = "Math Assessment Score") +
 scale_fill_manual(values=my_colors) #or you could enter the color numbers directly here
```

This worked during testing but ggplot does not like how you used size in the main aesthetic.

[image]

Comment: I just cut the whole thing and pasted directly from my r Studio, so little grammar stuff should be fixed...this works on my system, if you continue to have problems, post your code so I can see it.

Comment: @sconfluentus I suggest posting a picture of your output (graph). That is really helpful for future users to see what you provided and decide if that's what they want. Also increases chance of upvote. Cheers.