# assign custom colors to bubble chart from named list in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

Following some code examples here
([ggplot bubble graph custom colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45374586/ggplot-bubble-graph-custom-colors))
 to assign colors from a named list to bubble plot but to no avail. Trying to emulate the country_colors feature from gapminder package.
**The colors are not the desired from the named list I provide.**

```
 df <- data.frame(
      author = c("Atrhur", "Chloe", "Ernest", "Christian",
                 "Beth", "Wilson"),
      revenue = c(13796557L, 898702L, 15049136L, 28821608L, 44409616L, 21912235L),
      sold = c(492L, 62L, 548L, 38L, 182L, 879L)
    )

    mycolors <- structure(c("#7F3B08", "#833D07", "#873F07", "#8B4107", "#8F4407", 
                "#934407"), .Names = c("Atrhur", "Chloe", "Ernest", "Christian", 
                                       "Beth", "Wilson"))

    p <-
      ggplot(
        data = df,
        aes(
          x = revenue,
          y = sold,
          label = author
        )
      ) +
      geom_point(aes(size = revenue, alpha = 0.75, fill = author)) +
      scale_size_continuous(range = c(2, 20)) +
      geom_text_repel(segment.color = "gray") +
      theme(legend.position = "none") +
      scale_fill_manual(values = mycolors)
    p
```

[image]

Comment: Add `shape=21` as a parameter (not an `aes()`) to the call to `geom_point()`. Also, your code does not generate that plot. Also, the browns you're using are really hard to distinguish from one another.

Comment: that's the issue, this code gives me the plot you see. I don't know why

Comment: completely clear your environment or start a new R vanilla session and try again.